# Disprove: If $f,g : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ are Riemann Integrable and $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $\frac fg$ is Riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Disprove:  If $f,g : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ are Riemann Integrable and $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $\frac fg$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

I'm really not sure which counter-example to take here. Usually I would think about Dirichlet function or something similar to it but this won't work in this case.

Answer (score 7):

What about $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x\in (0,1]$, $g(0)=1$? Both $f$ and $g$ are integrable ($g$ has just one finite jump at $0^+$), but $f/g$ is unbounded so it is not integrable (not even in the improper sense).

Comment: GReyes, are you sure that $g(0)=0\,?\,$ In this way, $g$ ***does*** not have a finite jump at $0^+$, moreover it is not true that $g(x)\neq0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Angelo You are right.  That was a typo, I meant $g(0)=1$ of course..